# Checking Windows Store apps on ARM Simulator

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, simulator

I don't have ARM devices like Surface RT available in my country now, Is there any way to test my app on ARM Simulator from Visual Studio.

Comment: I have a Surface RT and so far there's nothing really different during debugging, it's just that it's a bit slower... so the big things to test are: resolution independence (you can do this via simulator) and slow Javascript/function calls that may slow down. Also, make sure to test touch support in simulator, since there is no hover support on a Surface.

Comment: Try Windows store labs , which could be the solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

As well said in the comment above, there is no ARM simulator available.

That said, an ARM device functions pretty much like a x86 PC. You just have to test all the resolutions and pixel densities available in the simulator.

And beware of the fact that a Surface RT can be more that 10 times slower than a typical PC. So if a computation takes half a second on your PC, it may take far too long on a Surface.